# How Magento validate products in cart for carts price rule and how to extract product from conditions_serialized column of the sale rules table?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.4.4, indexer, magento2.4.5

I need to create an indexer for cart price rules.
I decided to iterate the values from **sales_rules** table and extract the products from **conditions_serialized** coloumn.

My indexer file is like below.i Will share the `executeFull` method only here

```
public function executeFull(){
    $this->connection->truncateTable(
        $this->getTable('salaesrule_product_reminder_index')
    );

    $salesRules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1');;
    foreach ($salesRules as $salesRule) {
        
        $ruleId = $salesRule->getRuleId();
        $conditions = $salesRule->getConditionsSerialized();
        // Here i want to perform the insert task based on the product extract from above
    }
}
```

I am stuck here on extracting the **$conditions** return json and getting the product_id based on SKU.

Sample return json is something like below.

```
{
  "type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine",
  "attribute":null,
  "operator":null,
  "value":"1",
  "is_value_processed":null,
  "aggregator":"all",
  "conditions":[
   {
     "type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Found",
     "attribute":null,"operator":null,
     "value":"1",
     "is_value_processed":null,
     "aggregator":"all",
     "conditions":[
       {
         "type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product",
         "attribute":"sku",
         "operator":"==",
         "value":"16-02-07938, 16-02-07939, 16-02-08413",
         "is_value_processed":false,
         "attribute_scope":""
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

How magento do this kind of extraction on checking the cart rules against a product in cart? This kind of validation happen with produt Id or SKU?

Can anyone give me some insights on this question to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this way to overcome this task. Extracting from conditions_serialized is not a good practice to follow i guess, rather using sqlBuilder approach.

- Get All Available product Collections ( **Step 1** ).
- Get Conditions based on Cart Price Rules ( **Step 2** ).
- Pass All products & Conditions to **sqlBuilder** - ( **Step 3** ).
- Insert to indexer based on filtered products from **sqlBuilder** - ( **Step 4** ).

Sample Code is below.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ayakil\ModuleName\Model\Indexer\Action;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder;

class Full
{
private const INDEXER_TABLE_NAME = "table_indexer";
private const INDEXER_COLUMN_PRODUCTID = "product_id";
private const INDEXER_COLUMN_RULEID = "rule_id";
private const INDEXER_COLUMN_RULETITLE = "rule_title";

private $resource;
protected ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory;
protected $sqlBuilder;
public function __construct(
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    Builder $sqlBuilder
) {
    $this->resource    = $resource;
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->sqlBuilder = $sqlBuilder;
}

public function execute($salesRule)
{
    $products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();// Step 1
    $ruleId = $salesRule->getRuleId();
    $ruleTitle = $salesRule->getRuleTitle();
    $conditions = $salesRule->getConditions(); // Step 2
    $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($products, $conditions);//Step 3
    
    foreach ($products->getAllIds() as $productId) {
        //Step4
        $this->saveContent(
            $productId,
            $ruleId,
            $ruleTitle
        );
    }
}

private function saveContent(
    $productId,
    $ruleId,
    $ruleTitle
) {
    $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
    $tableName =  $connection->getTableName(self::INDEXER_TABLE_NAME);
    $indexingData = [
        self::INDEXER_COLUMN_PRODUCTID => $productId,
        self::INDEXER_COLUMN_RULEID => $ruleId,
        self::INDEXER_COLUMN_RULETITLE => $ruleTitle
    ];
    $connection->insert($tableName, $indexingData);
}
}
```

I hope this steps of the code definitely help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, cart price rules are used to offer discounts or promotions to customers based on certain conditions. These conditions can be specified using a variety of attributes, such as the products in the cart, the customer's billing or shipping address, or the payment method being used.

To validate the products in the cart against the conditions specified in a cart price rule, Magento uses a series of classes and methods in the Mage_SalesRule module.

The Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule class represents a cart price rule and contains a getConditions() method which returns an instance of the Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine class. This class represents the conditions specified in the conditions_serialized column of the salesrule database table, and contains a validate() method which can be used to evaluate these conditions against the products in the cart.

To extract the products from the conditions_serialized column, you can use the unserialize() function to deserialize the serialized data stored in this column. This will return an instance of the Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine class, which you can then use to access the individual conditions that make up the rule.

For example:

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1); // Load the rule with ID 1
$conditions = unserialize($rule->getConditionsSerialized()); // Extract the conditions from the serialized data

// Iterate over the conditions and perform some action on each one
foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
    // Perform some action on the condition
}
```

Note that this is just one way to extract the products from the conditions_serialized column and evaluate them against the cart. The specific implementation may vary depending on the specific requirements of your cart price rule.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed another method and i will update the answer